# Minimum value of $f(x) = {x^2 +18 \over x}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

How can I calculate the minimum value of

$$f(x) = {x^2 +18\over x}$$

**without** using a **graphing calculator** or any **computer software** ?

Comment: AM/${}{}{}{}$GM?

Comment: Do you know a connection between derivates and minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if $x>0$ then we get by $AM-GM$ $$x+\frac{18}{x}\geq 2\sqrt{18}=6\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: GREAT, doctor!!!

Comment: thanks mister, you are welcome! (n!)

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the function as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ \frac{18}{x}= \frac{1}{x} \underbrace{(x-\sqrt{18})^2}_{ \text{min occurs at } x=\sqrt{18}}+ \underbrace{ 6 \sqrt{2} }_{\text{mininimum value of the function is } 6\sqrt{2} }.
\end{eqnarray*}